# How can a network-wide-suspended account be posting questions and accepting answers?

Tags: support, bug, account-suspension, network-wide-suspension

Please reference this question: [Why was Booster 9's 29 engine static fire ended 2.36 seconds early?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/64121/6944)

The user's profile states that they have a network-wide suspension, yet they posted two questions and accepted an answer.

Answer (score 13):

I'd guess they'd created a sock with new credentials. This was spotted and escalated in some way and a merger was done after the questions were made and answers were accepted.

In *theory* a network suspended user can have their suspension waived on specific sites, and be suspended again later, but this is not the case here.

Comment: considering that the user was supposed to be suspended and not posting content, wouldn't a better course of action be deleting the sock user instead? That way the useful post can stay but the suspended user would not gain anything from then, not now nor when (if) the suspensions end.

Comment: Possibly but I'm not the one who did it. I'm speculating :D

Comment: More proof: [that question](https://space.stackexchange.com/review/first-questions/33760) got a 'first questions' review, so it was asked by an account that had never before asked a question.